# edit code to stop downloading on a certain month AND year

Tags: python, csv, urllib

I am currently using the following code to download some data. The code works well except when I want to stop the downloading on a certain month of a year.

E.g. If I want to stop downloading on month=02 and year=2019, it doesnt't work. I set max month to 02 and max year to 2019, however then it only downloads the second month of every year instead of up to the second month of 2019 (with every other month of the years before)

How can I edit my code to fix this problem?

Comment: you should do `year = year + 1` when your `month` is 12, not `max_month`, which is 01 in your code.

Comment: I already have `year = year +1`

Comment: I meant your code there is not correct, you should increment your `year` only when `month=12`, but you are not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues. First, change the line

```
while month <= max_month and year <= max_year:
```

to

```
while month < max_month or year < max_year:
```

as you would want the loop to continue when either condition is true. Then, change the line

```
if month == max_month:
```

to

```
if month == 12:
```

You should also remove the trailing `0`s (such as `month = 01`) as they will be considered octal in Python 2 (and raise a syntax error in Python 3).

Comment: Thank you, I was keeping the month with the `01` because of the web address of the file, but I guess I don't need it

Comment: @newtoR if you need to zero pad a number, there are format options and string methods for that.